# add action on UIButton in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift4

When I migrate a Swift 3 app to the 4 Xcode asked me to add `@objc` in front of a couple of my function.
And when I did it show me a warning that "@objc is deprecated"
I was wondering if there is any better solution for handling `addTarget` in Swift 4?

[image]

Here is my UIButton :

```
let playButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()
```

func :

```
@objc func playTapped() {
        let path = AudioPlayerManager.shared.audioFileInUserDocuments(name: "test")
    AudioPlayerManager.shared.playAudio(path: path)
}
```

it possible to add action to the button without using `#selector` and `@objc'?

Thanks.

Comment: There are more posts discussing this issue, and all of them end with the solution that will disable deprecated warnings. However I too wonder if there's a new, Swift 4, way to do this without using `@objc` since the `xcode` says it has been deprecated.

Comment: I remember reading about this, but I'm quite rusty. What happens if you just remove the `@objc` part ?

Comment: have you checked this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784758/programming-a-uibutton-is-not-working-in-swift-4-xcode-9-beta-6-cannot-add-targ#45795626

Comment: The warning does *not* say that `@objc` is deprecated; it says that Swift 3 `@objc` *inference* is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

**Try following instruction**

as use of swift 3 @objc interface in swift 4 is deprecated

[image]

Comment: That's a screenshot from http://evgenii.com/blog/disabling-swift3-objc-inference-in-xcode9/ without attribution, and the same solution as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380886/1187415.